# Transform an array with offset and arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm getting values from a google form, on one row, with an alternance of two types of data, 5 times. Like that :
`TypeA|TypeB|TypeA|TypeB|TypeA|TypeB|TypeA|TypeB|TypeA|TypeB`

I want to transform that in an array with two columns, on another sheet:

```
TypeA|TypeB
TypeA|TypeB
TypeA|TypeB
TypeA|TypeB
```

I managed to do it with that formula:
`=offset(DataSheet!$B$2,FLOOR((row()-2)/5),mod(row()-2,5)*2)`

I'd like to put that in an arrayformula, to avoid dragging the formula every time I have a form submission. I tried : `=arrayformula(offset(DataSheet!$B$2,FLOOR((row(B2:B)-2)/5),mod(row(B2:B)-2,5)*2))`
That works for the first line, but doesn't expand to the next line as expected/wished.

What am I missing?

Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nyN-V0ZjBsRU7-7I97lnLUQCsLpO8f27UlXtgoLa1j8?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
=QUERY({DataSheet!B2:C; DataSheet!D2:E; DataSheet!F2:G; DataSheet!H2:I; DataSheet!J2:K},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

or like this:

```
={FLATTEN(FILTER(DataSheet!B2:K, MOD(COLUMN(DataSheet!B:K), 2)=0)),
  FLATTEN(FILTER(DataSheet!B2:K, MOD(COLUMN(DataSheet!B:K)-1, 2)=0))}
```

[image]